# Work with code from bitbucket: how to make it work locally?

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I have access to a bitbucket repository and "downloaded" (whats the correct term?) it via SourceTree. Thus, I now have the code on my computer; but how should I continue?

It is a Java repository, so I copied it into Eclipse, which now gives me a load of import errors. What am I doing wrong here? Should I import all the libraries individually? Should it be executed from somewhere else (as opposed to Eclipse)?

I also assume that I shouldn't need to use git? I just work *with* the code, not *on* the code.

Comment: The correct term you're trying to find is `pulled` opposed to `downloaded`.

Comment: @Phantomazi got that. And what about fetching? That's the same?

Comment: Are you trying to use the code as a library? Are you trying to build it?

Comment: @omar Here's a question on SO explaining the difference between the two - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292357/what-are-the-differences-between-git-pull-and-git-fetch)

Comment: Read the README to see if you need external libraries in order to run the project without errors. As a side note, `git clone` is normally used rather than downloading the project. (unless it's what you meant by "downloading")

Comment: @dguay I see that the "master" map has a directory "libraries". Is there some fetch/clone/pull method which gets everything to make it work? Or should I get the libraries individually? And is Eclipse (or some IDE) the way to do it (I'm guessing it is)?

Comment: @omar `git clone` should get everything you need to run the program unless you need external libraries. I don't think the `libraries` directory has something to do about it. Normally the required libraries are listed in the README. (home page of the project in Bitbucket).